# SQL Server simple expression that set the result of comparing two datetimes2 variables into another bit variable won't work

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why can't SSMS run this simple SQL code?

```
declare @v bit
declare @d1 datetime2;
declare @d2 datetime2; 

set @d1 = CONVERT(datetime2, '2020-06-10');
set @d2 = sysdatetime();

set @v = @d1 > @d2;
-- error in this line at the comparison bracket
-- using: select @v = @d1 > @d2; won't work either
-- nor this will work: select @d1 > @d2;
```

Please note I'm not trying to deal with data from any table, I'm just trying to run individual SQL expressions for checking purposes

Comment: `bit` <> `boolean`, and the latter does not exist in T-SQL. And setting the result of a Boolean Expression to a `bit` doesn't make sense, as it's not a `boolean`.

Comment: Just use `case when @d1 > @d2 then 1 else 0 end)`.

Comment: @Larnu that don't make sense to me ! so I can't simply print/select  the result of a boolean expression ! nor store it in a variable of somekind !

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks , that what I needed

Comment: No, you can't, you'd need a `boolean` data type to store Boolean results, @Mohamed . `bit` is not a `boolean`.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for writing :)